# Open a new terminal shell in current directory

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm using the terminal shell of the MAC OSX (Unix environment) and I was wondering if it's possible to open a new terminal window in the current directory that I'm located in. Frequently I want to enter a file with a `vi` and see the contents of the folder simultaneously. CMD+N will open a new terminal with the default path being the home path `~`.

Is this possible?

If not, perhaps it's possible to split my terminal window, such that I can enter one file with `vi` will remain in the bash command line with the other half of the split-ed window?

Thanks a lot!
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just above the scrollbar there's a button that has a gray window with a bar across the middle.  If you click it, the terminal splits into two panes; you can drag the divider to resize the panes, and run `vi` in the bottom pane while keeping the original terminal contents in the top pane.  (You will then see two such buttons above the scrollbar for each pane; the bottom one closes the pane.)

To be clear:  this does not give you multiple usable terminals, just multiple views of the terminal's scrollback.  Terminal.app doesn't have a way to clone a tab, but development releases of [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/) [do](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/faq.shtml).

Comment: I see, that works! Is there a shortcut (keyboard button) to split the terminal? Also, it there a keyboard shortcut to switch between splitt-ed terminal windows?

Comment: Lastly, is it possible to vertically split it rather than horizontally?

Comment: It doesn't look like either is possible.

Comment: Man that is very very unfortunate.

Comment: How do I even switch between terminal windows, do you know??

Comment: You don't; the panes are just multiple views of the scrollback buffer, as I said.  The bottom pane is the actual terminal.

Comment: And all this time I wondered why anyone would want to use the split feature. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [cd to](https://github.com/jbtule/cdto0) for years, it is a little button that plugs into the finder toolbar and opens a terminal in that window.